# Excel Power Query - Is it possible to connect to Azure Blob Storage with SAS authentication or Azure AD account

Tags: excel, azure, powerquery, blobstore, azure-blob-storage

I am accessing a container from a Azure Blob Storage with Excel, we connect through "New Query" but only gives the option to access with the Account Key.

[image]

After logging the permissions are saved in Data source setting with the Account Key.

To access that Azure Blob Storage from VBA is enough with the function from Power Query AzureStorage.Blobs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/azurestorage-blobs).

¿Is It possible to do the same with SAS (Shared Access Signature) Token or Azure AD account instead of using the Account Key? I've looking and found nothing at the moment

Comment: I'm not aware of the AAD option in Excel, abut Power BI connector supports it finally (CDM Folder View is just Beta). If your final goal is a dashboard or some pivot, Power BI might cut it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could connect with sas, however it's not data from azure, in my test it could work with from web.

I generate the sas url with read,write permissions and use HTTP protocol, then in the excel paste the url and replace `https` to `http`. Then you will be able to get the data.

[image]

[image]

If use Power Query, choose New Source-> Other Sources-> Web then it's same with excel get data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can access a certain file and load it to the sheet, but I am not able to list all the blobs in a a table format as I did with the Azure Blob Storage .Do you know any workaround for that?

Comment: What do you mean `not able to list all the blobs in a a table format as I did with the Azure Blob Storage .`? Please make a detailed description about your problem.

Comment: Not able to list all the blobs of a specific prefix in the container, so instead of writing the url with the Blob, the prefix. Following your example something like this: 
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/test?sas_token

Comment: I have a test looks like it's not able to list container files with from web  way, just like you use a browser you could not access container sas url.  Or maybe I use a wrong way.